# Como agrupar resultado de una consulta

Tags: mysql

Necesito relacionar dos tablas con **INNER JOIN**.

En una tabla **relacion** tengo `Estudiante`

En la tabla **estudiantes** tengo `Estudiante`, `Nombre`, `Grado`.

Necesito relacionar en una consulta ambas tablas y que el resultado sea uno.

La consulta que tengo.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Id_Estudiante, u.Id_Estudiante, Nombres, Grado FROM relacion INNER JOIN estudiantes WHERE relacion.r = estudiantes.u
```

El fin de lo que quiero es que me muestre el `Id_Estudiante`, el nombre del estudiante y el grado que está cursando.

El campo `Estudiante` son las iniciales del nombre del estudiante. Ejemplo:

```
María Alejandra Ortiz = maortiz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo entender al decir que

> Necesito relacionar en una consulta ambas tablas y que el resultado
>   **sea uno**.

Lo que quieres es que no se repitan los resultados, si es así, tienes 2 opciones.

**DISTINCT**

```
select distinct(r.Id_Estudiante), e.Nombres, e.grado
from relacion r
inner join estudiantes e on e.Id_Estudiante = r.Id_Estudiante
```

**GROUP BY**

```
select r.Id_Estudiante, e.Nombres, e.grado
from relacion r
inner join estudiantes e on e.Id_Estudiante = r.Id_Estudiante
group by r.Id_Estudiante
```

Comment: Me sirvió con el `select distinct` muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Y cómo le digo que lo ordene los nombres de manera ascendente?

Comment: @CarlosOrtiz cambia tu pregunta por que la verdadera es que hace un inner join

Comment: @JackNavaRow ¿O creo una nueva pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la documentación de SQL. Lo que deberías hacer es indicar los campos de relación en la cláusula `INNER JOIN` con el formato `INNER JOIN [tabla] ON [campo_tabla1]=[campo_tabla2]`

Básicamente:

```
SELECT relacion.Id_Estudiante, estudiantes.Nombre, estudiantes.Grado
FROM relacion
INNER JOIN estudiantes ON estudiantes.Id_Estudiante=relacion.Id_estudiante
```

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 'relacion.Id_Estudiante' in 'field list'` me aparece eso, y la columna si se llama así.

Comment: Podrías agregar la estructura de tus tablas, ya que lo que te comentaron deberia funcionar sin problemas, y si te esta diciendo que no encuentra la columna entonces debemos mirar la estrctura.

Comment: Creería que en `FROM relacion`, falta ponerle un nombre, o un apodo por decirlo así, por eso es más sencillo trabajarlo como @JaimitoPaco lo hizo. Que a la tabla **estudiante** le puso la e y así al ponerlo en la consulta `FROM relacion r` y en `INNER JOIN estudiante e`

Comment: Sí, por supuesto que se pueden utilizar alias. No lo he hecho porque entendía que el ejemplo quedaba más simple y claro sin ellos.